# Как сделать ImageView круглым?

Tags: android, android-imageview

Как динамически добавленный ImageView сделать круглым?
Если я не ошибаюсь, то CircleImageView работает только в xml.

Comment: Всё, что работает в xml разметке можно сделать из кода, так как в конечном счёте все view это просто Java классы.

Comment: @eugeneek Вы правы. Надо было всего лишь вместо ImageView прописать CircleImageView

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать следующий метод:

```
public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
    int targetWidth = 50;
    int targetHeight = 50;
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, 
                        targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
        ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
        (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), 
        ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
        Path.Direction.CCW);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
    canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, 
        new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
        sourceBitmap.getHeight()), 
        new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);
    return targetBitmap;
}
```

А использовать так:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(getRoundedShape(((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap()));
```

## UPD#1

Нужно убедиться действительно ли ваш `imageView.getDrawable()` может быть преобразован в `BitmapDrawable` (чтобы избежать `IllegalCastExceptions`).
Если, например, вы используете слои в своем изображении, этот фрагмент будет немного отличаться:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(getRoundedShape(((BitmapDrawable)((LayerDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getDra‌​wable(0)).getBitmap(‌​));
```